# Interval-scheduled RxJava observables take more time than specified

Tags: java, multithreading, reactive-programming, rx-java

In the following piece of code, the observable is supposed to fire off every 300 milliseconds. I spiced it up by simulating background activity that takes 1 second. I was expecting that since I am using a scheduler that uses a thread pool underneath, the interval observable would keep firing on a new thread every 300 milliseconds. What happens instead, is that the interval observable waits for an entire second every time, before firing off again. Is this the desired behavior? How could one force it to fire off in parallel, if a task takes more than the requested amount of time?

Here is the code:

```
Observable
            .interval(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Schedulers.io())
                .doOnNext(new Action1<Long>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Long aLong) {
                        System.out.println("action thread: " + Thread.currentThread());
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                })
                .map(new Func1<Long, Float>() {
                    @Override
                    public Float call(Long aLong) {
                        final double result = Math.random();
                        return new Float(result);
                    }
                })
                .takeWhile(new Func1<Float, Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public Boolean call(Float aFloat) {
                        return aFloat >= 0.01f;
                    }
                })
            .subscribe(new Action1<Float>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Float aFloat) {
                    System.out.println("observing thread: " + Thread.currentThread());
                    System.out.println(aFloat);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observables are sequential in nature so if you put in a sleep such as in example, you are blocking the whole sequence. To do background computation, you have to move it to another thread via `observeOn` or `subscribeOn`. In this case, you can `flatMap`/`concatMapEager` in another observable that does the sleeping and merge the results back into the main sequence:

```
Observable.interval(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
.flatMap(t -> Observable.fromCallable(() -> { 
        Thread.sleep(1000);
     }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()))
.map(...)
.takeWhile(...)
.subscribe(...)
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. I looked deeper into the code that does scheduling, and it is clearly stated there that it will block on running operations, so they must be executed elsewhere. It took me a bit of time to wrap my head around your particular use of flatMap, but it seems to make total sense. flatMap is a convenience method that merges all the separate streams into one unified Observable stream. All makes sense now. Thank you!